# Angular Issue parsing Float

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm using a filter to get totals from dynamic data in ng-repeat.  My probably is that I cannot get the decimals down to 2 places.  Here is my filter:

```
app.filter('sumByKey', function() {
    return function (data, key) {
        if (typeof (data) === 'undefined' || typeof (key) === 'undefined') {
            return 0;
        }

        var sum = 0;
        for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            //sum += parseFloat(data[i][key]);
            sum += Math.round((data[i][key]) * 1e12) / 1e12;
        }

        return sum;
    };
});
```

I commented out "parseFloat" because it didn't work and trying to use "toFixed(2)" gave unusual unreadible results.  I have tested this in IE and Chrome and I still get the following:

[image]

This is not a duplicate to the question that is answered by "toFixed(2)" as I stated above as "toFixed(2)" returns long crazy unreadable numbers.

Any assistance is greatly appreciated!

Comment: Could you elaborate on what mean when `toFixed(2)` "gave unusual unreadible results"?

Comment: Note that `toFixed` has a return value of type string, not a number. Which might explain your issue.

Comment: Is there a way to fix that?

Comment: Don't just post images of errors, post text of the error (some can't see the images).

Comment: Thanks RobG, I didn't realize that some can't see the images.

Comment: @RobG Out of curiosity, are you visually impaired or using a text based browser?

Comment: Could you provide a *small* set of sample data with the expected output?

Comment: I'd like .8300000001 to be .83, is that what you mean?

Comment: No. You are giving multiple numbers to this function and expecting a sum of the rounded numbers. What are the numbers and what is the expected output of the function as a whole?

Comment: @JonKoops—neither, I'm at a site where certain domains (such as http://i.stack.imgur.com) are blocked. Why? Dunno, I guess because "they" can. Interesting that you asked about accessibility, I've just done a major project on that and now have a great use case for not to posting textual information as an image. :-)

Comment: @Jon Koops, the numbers are in the table.  It is supposed to be summing the columns.  It is summing the columns correctly.  It is just having issues with the decimals.

Comment: What is strange is that it is not having a problem with ALL of the decimals.  If you look at the table, some of the decimal columns work fine.

Comment: I understand that there are values. I want to have example input to the function and the expected output of the function.

Comment: It's kind of difficult to give you an example other than what's in the table as it is all dynamic.  What calls the function is "<td align='center'>{{y.yearDetails|sumByKey:'" + $scope.columns[i].vchAssociatedDetailColumn + "'}}</td>"  and what is passed is exactly what is in the table.  I'm not sure what else to give you.

Comment: I undestand. I just want _example_ input that fails to have reproducible code with the bug. Because the code I run just works like expected. I cannot test against arbitrary things like "long crazy unreadable numbers".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try the Number.toPrecision function, e.g.

```
var sum = 0;
for (var i = data.length - 1; i >= 0; i--)
    sum += parseFloat(data[i][key]);

return parseFloat(sum.toPrecision(2));
```

Comment: Awesome!  That it did it!  Thanks a million!